# Tesseract OCR, Python and Windows XP

Tags: python, windows, ocr, tesseract

Evening everyone,

I am trying to use a tesseract (OCR) python wrapper found here, with the first example:
https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/CodeSnippets

I am using Python27, on a Windows XP machine. Everything is 32 bit.

I have installed all the dependencies, found in this guide:
http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/install-opencv-in-windows-for-python.html

I checked the environment variable:
TESSDATA_PREFIX = C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata\

Then finally, I try to execute the script in cmd.exe:
"python.exe 119.py" (119.py being the first example in CodeSnippets, with a different image ofc), and I get the following error:

C:\Python27>python.exe 119.py
Error opening data file C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdatatessdata/eng.trai
neddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent d
irectory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!

Now, the only thing I notice here is the slash (/) instead of backslash (\) before the eng.traineddata, that's the bit automatically added after the environment variable. 
I am hoping this is the only thing that needs fixing, but I have no clue on how to do it, and that is why I am here... :)

So, seasoned programmers, binary Gods, please help me out.
Thanks in advance. :)

p.s.

I need to be using a Windows machine for this project, so swiching to Linux as an easy way out is not an option here. :(

Comment: The error message tells you not to include the tessdata directory in the path and displays a path with "tessdatatessdata" - its obviously appending the path again. Try removing it from the path.

Comment: Omg am I this worn out... Ok, yes, obviously... Now I just keep getting python crashes after execution, but I get some output (though wrong)... Thanks for the input, can't believe I was this careless... -.-

Comment: p.s. How do I up vote you on a comment? :))

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and after i set it via this command in cmd, it accepted.

```
set TESSDATA_PREFIX=C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata
```

you need to use forward slash even windows accepts backslash.